# powers of a unit in a number field never in a subfield

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

By using the ranks of the unit groups, one can see that if $K$ is not a CM field, then the unit group of $K$ contains a unit not in any subfield.

However, is it also possible to find a unit, $\epsilon$, in such $K$ such that $\epsilon^n$ is also never in any subfield for every non-zero integer $n$?

I suspect the answer is yes, but have not been able to find a reference or a proof myself.

Note that the above-mentioned rank argument alone does not suffice.
E.g., Sage shows that the unit group of $Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$ can have $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ as an element of a set of fundamental units, whose square is clearly in $Q(\sqrt{3})$.

So my questions are:
does anyone have ideas for a proof of such a result?
counterexamples?
or references to such a result?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the root $\epsilon = \frac{3+\sqrt 5}2$ of $X^2-3X+1$ is a unit in the quadratic extension $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$ an certainly no power $\epsilon^n$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ is rational as it would still have to be a unit.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Hagen. You are correct. The answer to my question is always yes in real quadratic fields (or any field whose unit group is of rank 1) and for the reason that you state here. But my question is whether the answer is yes for **all** number fields which are not CM-fields.

Comment: @Pi314 If I am not mistaken, Hagen intended to show that your conjecture is wrong in this case?

Comment: @awllower Let $P(K)$ equal the statement "$K$'s integers contain a unit none of whose powers lie in a subfield." OP is asking if $K$-not-CM implies $P(K)$. How could Hagen providing a single example of a $K$ where $P(K)$ holds be a counterexample to this implication?

Comment: @anon It seems then that I must have been mistaken. Thanks for the clarification: I see the matter now. Sorry for any possible confusion.